# Difference between getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable and getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundDrawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-windowmanager

What is the difference between them? As far as I can see they both do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to sources, you will find [PhoneWindow.class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java) that have implementation of `Window.setBackgroundDrawable` method:

```
@Override
public final void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable != mBackgroundDrawable || mBackgroundResource != 0) {
        mBackgroundResource = 0;
        mBackgroundDrawable = drawable;
        if (mDecor != null) {
            mDecor.setWindowBackground(drawable);
        }
        if (mBackgroundFallbackResource != 0) {
            mDecor.setBackgroundFallback(drawable != null ? 0 : mBackgroundFallbackResource);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it calls different method of DecorView `setWindowBackground`:

```
public void setWindowBackground(Drawable drawable) {
    if (getBackground() != drawable) {
        setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.getPadding(mBackgroundPadding);
        } else {
            mBackgroundPadding.setEmpty();
        }
        drawableChanged();
    }
}
```

Which is actually use method `DecorView.setBackgroundDrawable` but also provides additional logic for `Window`. So I would suggest you to use `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable()`.